# How can you find how many redundant disks you have in a RAID using with mdadm?

Tags: raid

I have a host that is experiencing a few disk failures.  I didn't setup the RAID on this host but I believe it was setup as RAID 6.  Is there any way I can find how many redundant disks are availible on this host?  You would think that 'mdadm --detail /dev/md0' would give you this information, but it doesn't.

Here's the output I get from that command:

```
    /dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Oct 22 14:22:34 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 41023535616 (39123.09 GiB 42008.10 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953501696 (1863.00 GiB 2000.39 GB)
   Raid Devices : 23
  Total Devices : 23
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Feb  1 10:53:48 2017
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 23
Working Devices : 23
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : 0
           UUID : 1c33c71f:4bfcbdb2:5e8c8da0:a6d0291f
         Events : 585

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     202       32        0      active sync   /dev/sdc
       1     202       48        1      active sync   /dev/sdd
       2     202       64        2      active sync   /dev/sde
       3     202       80        3      active sync   /dev/sdf
       4     202       96        4      active sync   /dev/sdg
       5     202      112        5      active sync   /dev/sdh
       6     202      128        6      active sync   /dev/sdi
       7     202      144        7      active sync   /dev/sdj
       8     202      160        8      active sync   /dev/sdk
       9     202      176        9      active sync   /dev/sdl
      10     202      192       10      active sync   /dev/sdm
      11     202      208       11      active sync   /dev/sdn
      12     202      224       12      active sync   /dev/sdo
      13     202      240       13      active sync   /dev/sdp
      14     202     4096       14      active sync   /dev/sdq
      15     202     4352       15      active sync   /dev/sdr
      16     202     4608       16      active sync   /dev/sds
      17     202     4864       17      active sync   /dev/sdt
      18     202     5120       18      active sync   /dev/sdu
      19     202     5376       19      active sync   /dev/sdv
      20     202     5632       20      active sync   /dev/sdw
      21     202     5888       21      active sync   /dev/sdx
      22     202     6144       22      active sync   /dev/sdy
```

Is it as easy as working backwards from the fact that this RAID 6 has 23 disks, therefore it should have at least 2 disks of redundancy?

Comment: A 21+2 R6 seems a bit silly to me, I know it *CAN* work but it's quite risky at that ratio and means rebuilds will take longer - consider lower ratios please

Comment: cat /proc/mdstat

Comment: Totally agree that this ratio is too low.  I think we'll switch to a different raid config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, exactly. RAID6 in `mdadm` means two disks can fail without data loss. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_6

NB: The report shows that your array is fine, without any disk failures. What's up with that?

Comment: We've got a bunch of hosts all configured with the same RAID.  This is from a healthy one, but it has the same configuration.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it as easy as working backwards from the fact that this RAID 6 has 23 disks, therefore it should have at least 2 disks of redundancy?

It does not matter how many disks you have so long as you have the working minimum for RAID 6. You don't work back from 23 to get 'at least 2', it is a fact that for RAID 6 you can lose 2 disks and no more.

You may want to take a look at the `/proc/mdstat` file to get an overview of the mdraid disks that you have.